# How to use save 2 editText to 2 spinners in same Activity

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I want to make the second "save" button save the second editText to second spinner like the first does  this is the code I'm trying to use and thanks to cricket_007 for helping me with the whole question

```
    List<String> pn, txt;
Spinner sp1, sp2;
Button b, b1, b2, b3;
EditText et, et1;

ArrayAdapter<String> adp1, adp2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    setupSpinners();

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adp1.add(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText(null);
        }

    });

    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adp2.add(et1.getText().toString());
            et1.setText(null);
        }

    });
}

public void setupSpinners() {

    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    pn = new ArrayList<String>();
    txt = new ArrayList<String>();
    txt.add("Sorry Boss I'cant go today i'm sick");
    pn.add("123456789");

    adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, pn);
    adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, txt);

    sp1.setAdapter(adp1);
    sp1.setSelection((pn.size() - 1));
    sp2.setAdapter(adp2);
    sp2.setSelection((txt.size() - 1));

    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            sp1.setSelection(arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }


    });
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            sp2.setSelection(arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
```

[image: Layout Snap]

Comment: what is the problem that you face??

Comment: I want to make 2 equal buttons to store 2 different texts in different spinners

Comment: Did you plan on using `sp2.setAdapter` at any point?

Comment: I'm going to edit the question code to the part i'm trying to do it

Comment: You got an error, so that doesn't seem to be an answer. You can [edit] your question again with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to setup the adapter and spinner's once.

Whatever you are trying to do between the click events, just gets added into `onItemSelected`, but in order to set the selection of the other spinner, it needs some data, so add an adapter to it.

And, for your latest edit of the question, you've not indented the code correctly, but you've set some stuff within the `onClick` of the button that shouldn't be there.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> pn, txt;
    Spinner sp1, sp2;
    Button b, b1, b2, b3;
    EditText et, et1;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1, adp2; // Added

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setupSpinners();

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adp1.add(et.getText().toString());  // Changed
                et.setText("");
            }
        });

       b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adp2.add(et1.getText().toString());
                et1.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    public void setupSpinners() {

        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        pn = new ArrayList<String>();
        txt = new ArrayList<String>();
        txt.add("Sorry Boss I'cant go today i'm sick");
        pn.add("123456789");

        adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, pn);
        adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, txt);

        sp1.setAdapter(adp1);
        sp1.setSelection((pn.size() - 1));
        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                sp2.setSelection(arg2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });

        sp2.setAdapter(adp2);

    }
}
```